# Getting forbidden 403 error only on https but url http working fine

Tags: codeigniter, ssl, amazon-ec2, http-status-code-403, apache2.4

on my server I have wordpress site on root and codeigniter project as sub folder in wordpress and I made subdomain for codeigniter project. Both are working fine without SSL Now I want to apply SSL on subdomain project while applying ssl on this I am facing issue. When I am opening site by using https://subdomain.example.com it is giving me forbidden 403 error.

Following is the example of my sites hosted on apache. I had symbolic link for my root wordpress project.

http://example.com - working fine - wordpress project on root

http://subdomain.example.com - working fine - codeigniter project under wordpress project folder

https://subdomain.example.com - getting forbidden error

Following is my apache ssl virtual host file data.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost *:443>
                ServerAlias subdomain.example.com
                ServerName subdomain.example.com
                DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpress

                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

                SSLEngine on
                SSLCertificateFile      /home/ubuntu/wordpress/cdq/my-ssl-certifications/fc1d71b08ac8aab1.crt
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/ubuntu/wordpress/cdq/my-ssl-certifications/host.key
                SSLCertificateChainFile /home/ubuntu/wordpress/cdq/my-ssl-certifications/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </FilesMatch>
                <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </Directory>
                <Directory /var/www/html/wordpress>
                        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                        AllowOverride All
                        Require all granted
                </Directory>



        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

htaccess of wordpress project

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} subdomain.example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1 [L] 

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

htaccess of subfolder project

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Is there anything in your error logs?

Comment: nothing is in my logs regarding this

Comment: Have you chown your ci project to www-data?

Comment: yes ParkerDell . Its working fine when I am using http in url just getting forbidden error when using https

Comment: there is no need of doing this in .htaccess of wordpress site
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} subdomain.example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1 [L]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally resolved the issue. Issue was with the permissions of project folder structure. Now everything is working fine

Answer (score 2):

There is some permission related issue in your configuration :

```
<Directory /var/www/html/wordpress>
                    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                    AllowOverride All
                    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

it require granted for all files. So all you have to do is make it like :

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/wordpress">
     AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

**P.S.** *I have modified your file and you use it like :*

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerAlias subdomain.example.com
    ServerName subdomain.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpress
<Directory "/var/www/html/wordpress">
   AllowOverride All
</Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    SSLEngine on
            SSLCertificateFile      /home/ubuntu/wordpress/cdq/my-ssl-certifications/fc1d71b08ac8aab1.crt
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/ubuntu/wordpress/cdq/my-ssl-certifications/host.key
            SSLCertificateChainFile /home/ubuntu/wordpress/cdq/my-ssl-certifications/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
            <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            </FilesMatch>
            <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            </Directory>
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
</VirtualHost>
```

There is no major change. I just modify it according to my working file. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks @Deepak Sharma . But my problem is solved by setting the permissions correctly. Basically the main issue was permissions